# ROS Docker repository details

Tags: docker, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
Can anyone provide me the details of ROS docker repository (github), where ros docker installation files are maintained?
Is there any guide on how can I contribute there?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349211/ros-docker-repository-details/) by [Hardik Rathod](https://answers.ros.org/users/52767/hardik-rathod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you click on one of that tags of official ROD Docker images on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/ros)  (tags are located on Description tab) then it will take you to the source code of Dockerfiles located on GitHub - I think that is what you are looking for:

https://github.com/osrf/docker_images

---

Originally posted by [viktor.holova](https://answers.ros.org/users/51651/viktor.holova/) with karma: 201 on 2020-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hardik Rathod](https://answers.ros.org/users/52767/hardik-rathod/) on 2020-04-14**:
Thank you. This is what I was looking for.

**Comment by [viktor.holova](https://answers.ros.org/users/51651/viktor.holova/) on 2020-04-14**:
You are welcome Hardik

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-14**:
@Hardik Rathod: instead of closing the question, please mark it as answered by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. It will turn green.